# In Python with Shapely, how to get a better shape when removing from a large polygon a smaller polygon on the edges of it?

Tags: python, shapely

In Python with Shapely (1.8.X or 2.X), let's say we have a large polygon that contains inside one or more small polygons that sit on the edges of the large polygon. If I just do the difference of the large polygon with the small polygons, we'll get a shape that has "holes" where the small polygons were. However, I would like to improve this final shape to get rid of the lines that surrounded these small polygons, in order to have a more "closed" shape.

Ideally, after that, we will also automatically identify whether yes/no, the final result should be kept or if it became too small in the end (eg using its area).

Simple example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
large_polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 4), (6, 4), (6, 0)])
small_polygon = Polygon([(4, 1), (4, 3), (6, 3), (6, 1)])

result_polygon = large_polygon.difference(small_polygon)
```

Visually, we would get something like that for the "result_polygon"
[image: Current result_polygon #1]

But what I would like to obtain would exclude the border there were around the small_polygon (the green rectangle here) [image: Final result I would like to obtain]

This is however just a simple case, but in the end, I would like to use it over much more complex cases that just basic rectangles, with polygons with less straight lines, like for example, obtaining good separated polygons in the following figure, if we remove the "brown" polygons from the larger "yellow" polygons:
[image: Example of more complex cases]

To do this, I think one possibility would be to divide the final polygon (from the difference of the large polygon with the smaller polygons) into several small parts (to form a multipolygon). We could then delete the parts we want to remove from it (for example according to their area) or just save them separately. I tried something for this that would try to split the polygon in multipolygon by trying to identify the parallel or perpendicular points, but it didn't really work with the proposed simple case.